# ¿Por qué no me está escuchando el evento Click?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo éste pequeño ejercicio de Slider. El botón a la derecha que ejecuta la función slideNext funciona, pero el botón a la izquierda que ejecuta la función slidePrev no funciona. Me he dado cuenta que la función hace su trabajo al invocarla directamente desde la consola del navegador, y también funciona agregando el atributo onclick en HTML, sin embargo no logro hacer que funcione mediante addEventListener. Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas y disculpen la novatada!

```
var buttonNext = document.getElementById("next");
var buttonPrev = document.getElementById("prev");

buttonNext.addEventListener("click", slideNext);
buttonPrev.addEventListener("click", slidePrev);

function slideNext() {
    document.querySelector("#Tanya").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#John").style.display = "flex";

}

function slidePrev() {
    document.querySelector("#Tanya").style.display = "flex";
    document.querySelector("#John").style.display = "none";

}
```

[image: Slider]

Comment: puedes incluir el fragmento del código html de los botones y de donde estás llamando al script ?

Comment: Estoy seguro que el error se debe a algun error de tipeo a la hora de apuntar al id del elemento HTML, o tambien la otra es que se estuviese cargando primero el script y luego la pagina, pero pues... si dices que un boton funciona y el otro no entonces el problema de que se carga primero el script antes que la pagina no tendria sentido.